# Prime Check JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

What have I done wrong with this code? It can't print anything on the console.
Here it is the description of the problem:

Implement a javascript function that accepts an array containing an integer N and uses an expression to check if given N is prime (i.e. it is divisible without remainder only to itself and 1).

```
var n = ['2'];

function isPrime(n) {

    if (n < 2) {
      return false;
    }

    var isPrime = true;

    for(var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i += 1) {
      if (n % i === 0) {
        isPrime = false;
      }
    }

    return isPrime;
}

return isPrime(n);
```

Comment: How did you try to log to the console. You never did this in your code snippet. And also you are defining an array "n" but use it as a scalar value.

Comment: Still cannot print the answer

Comment: "Still cannot print the answer" --- this is not a proper problem explanation. Otherwise "try harder" is a valid answer to it.

Comment: couples of error, seem haven't run properly JS code yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple errors in your code.

First, you need to check for every integer between 2 and Math.sqrt(n) inclusively. Your current code returns true for 4.

I don't think this is in a function, so you need to omit `return` from `return isPrime(n)` and replace it with a function wich prints out the return value of the funnction, like `alert` or `console.log`.

`n` is not a number, it's an array. You need to either make n a number, or call the function with `isPrime(n[0])`.

The correct code is

```
var n = 2;

function isPrime(n) {

    if (n < 2) {
      return false;
    }

    var isPrime = true;

    for(var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1) {
      if (n % i === 0) {
        isPrime = false;
      }
    }

    return isPrime;
}

alert(isPrime(n));
```

Note: You can change `n += 1` to `n++`, and it works the same way.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, but his current problem is "It can't print anything on the console"

Comment: @evolutionxbox I actually don't know JQuery, and I don't actually think it would make it shorter.

Comment: @Bálint I see, so you could have replaced the whole code with `console.log('foo');`.

Comment: Boo. My joke failed. Boo.

Comment: @zerkms There's a difference between solving the current problem and interpreting the question too seriously

Comment: @Bálint check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324950/prime-check-javascript/38325141?noredirect=1#comment64065188_38325073

Answer (score 1):

`n` is an array, you want to access first element in the array and convert it to number first.

try replacing

```
return isPrime(n);
```

with

```
return isPrime(parseInt(n[0],10));
```

Your for-loop condition also needs a little modification

```
for(var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1) { //observe that i is not <= Math.sqrt(n)
```

Comment: Some explanation might be helpful.

Comment: And now check their task :-)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of little errors:

```
var n = 2;//<--no need to put n in an array

function isPrime(n) {
if (n < 2) {
    return false;
}
var isPrime = true;

for(var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i += 1) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
        isPrime = false;
    }
}
return isPrime;
}

isPrime(n);//<--no need for "return"
```

Comment: Good catch! Was trying to help with the code rather than the math.

Answer (score 0):

As to no output being printed, it is because you need to use `console.log`.

Replace `return isPrime(n);` with `console.log(isPrime(n));`.

Comment: It will not solve their problem though. But it's not your answer that is bad, but the question is asked poorly.

Comment: I don't think this answer was added to resolve all the issues OP has. I think it's a valid answer if it contributes to solving the question.

Comment: It does not resolve all the issues probably - his main issue was that he can not print to the console. I answered how to do that. I am assuming this is a school task, and once he has this, he will test his code and try to solve the remaining issues.
- Oh I think I just interpreted that as his main question, but it's very well possible that he is asking for all the mistakes, my bad -

Comment: @evolutionxbox the problem with the question is that the "why this code does not work" does not fit into the whole SO model well. Not only the questions themselves are poor, but the answers don't contribute into the community: the question and its answers are only valuable for literally one person.

Comment: (the OP is not a dude) --- Also @zerkms that is true.

Comment: I agree with that @zerkms. It is asked in a way that is not good. Perhaps changing the title to "why does return statement not print result" would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Full working code:

`var n = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']; // you can use as many values as you want
    function isPrime(n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        var isPrime = true;
        for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1) { // Thanks to gurvinder372's comment
            if (n % i === 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
    n.forEach(function(value) { // this is so you can iterate your array with js
        console.log('is ' + value + ' prime or not? ' +  isPrime(value)); // this so you can print a message in the console
    });
    /*
    // Another approach of parsing the data, uncomment this piece of code and comment the one above to see it in action (both will give the same result)
    for (index = 0; index < n.length; ++index) {
        console.log('is ' + n[index] + ' prime or not? ' +  isPrime(n[index])); // this so you can print a message in the console
    }
    */`